Why can't I add RESOLVED in the title?

Does anyone know if there is a way to increase the power of the PIC16F pin using MPLABX?

You are not supposed to change the title to mark something as solved, that's not how this site works.
To mark a question as resolved, you accept one of the answers (click the tick mark next to the answer). This indicates that a solution has been identified:

For futher reading, this is discussed in detail in the help centre.

Note also that questions that have been marked this way show up differently in lists like the home page or questions page. So adding "solved" to the title does nothing that other UI elements aren't already doing.

To add - if the OP isn't satisfied with any of the provided answers, but have resolved the question differently, they should add their own answer and accept it.

@EugeneSh. In this specific instance the OP did answer their own question, as you suggested as a valid option.

As Tom said, that's what accepting an answer does - it marks a question as resolved.
I notice you have not done that. It looks like you discovered the answer to your own question; you should accept your answer.
